# How to get Current Indentity Value as Null or 0 for blank table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a blank table, i want to get Next current identity Id for that table,

```
Select IDENT_CURRENT ('CityPhotoGallery') + IDENT_INCR('CityPhotoGallery')
```

in this case its giving Next idnetity ID as 2

It should be 1

Comment: What is your sql version?

Comment: Why do you want this number? By the time you've obtained this information, it *may* be out of date (because one or more connections may perform one or more inserts between you asking the question and being able to do anything with the answer). What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to Get Next Identity ID while inserting, But If Table is blank then Its giving 2 as Next Identity ID, After Inserting first Row again Its Giving 2 As next identity ID

Comment: The only reliable way to determine the identity value is to perform the insert and then use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or an `OUTPUT` clause. There is **no** reliable way to determine, *before* an `INSERT` happens, what value will be assigned. And when I asked for the "actual problem", I mean that this is your attempt at a *solution* to some problem you've not told us about. Your end goal is not, merely, to find a particular number and then do nothing with it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> When the IDENT_CURRENT value is NULL (because the table has never
>   contained rows or has been truncated), the IDENT_CURRENT function
>   returns the seed value.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

This means that indeed if your seed is 1, you get `IDENT_CURRENT()=1` both *before* and *after* inserting the first row.

Even though I agree that you should describe on a higher level what you'd like to achieve, in this case you'd need a `CASE WHEN` to take into account if the table is empty.

In particular, you should be careful because:

> Be cautious about using IDENT_CURRENT to predict the next generated
>   identity value. The actual generated value may be different from
>   IDENT_CURRENT plus IDENT_INCR because of insertions performed by other
>   sessions.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

Answer (score 0):

NULLIF(IDENT_CURRENT ('CityPhotoGallery'),1)

I think it would work for new table

Comment: If, 1 row is already is there with Identity ID , in that condition also its giving Null